# How to establish no-delete safety for private git server?

Tags: git

I am new to shifting from github.com to a private git server.

I read that you can use a single "git" user with authorized_keys or use gitolite or gitosis.

But how can I make sure, that only git commands can be executed on the server, and that no delete command can be executed? I think there are also git commands which can delete or empty the git repository.

But is there a possibility that no one can execute "rm -fR" ?

Answer (score 0):

`gitolite` will allow you to have that control and more.